# Matplotlib subplot from SQLite database very slow

Tags: sqlite, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter, subplot

I am working on a GUI that selects data from an SQLite database and plots it in a 3x3 grid using Tkinter. The more subplots I add the slower it gets every time I try executing it. Below is a snippet for one subplot in my code.

The grid of subplots changes depending on which of the radio button options the user is selecting, hence the "if(option.get()==1)" line. I essentially repeat everything from the "CC.execute" line for every single subplot. Is there something I could be doing to speed this up so it doesn't take 3-4 seconds to plot one 3x3 grid?

```py
def display():
     if(option.get()==1):      
         frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width=675, height=400) 
         frame1.grid(column=1, row=7, rowspan=16, columnspan=2)

         ## Plot # 1
         CC.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1')#
         x1=[]
         y1=[]

         for row in CC.fetchall(): 
             x1.append(row[0])#
             y1.append(row[1])#
         figure1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(13.5,9), dpi=50)
         ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(331)
         line1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, frame1)
         line1.get_tk_widget().grid(column=1, row=6, rowspan=6, columnspan=3)             
         ax1.plot(x1,y1)

         ax1.set_xlabel('Xaxis \n [Number]')
         ax1.set_ylabel('Yaxis')
         ax1.set_title('Y vs. X')

         figure1.tight_layout(pad=1, w_pad=1)
```

Comment: Try adding `print` statements and checking what takes up the most amount of time.

Comment: From the looks of it you are creating a new `tk.Frame` every time you execute the `display` function. It definitely will get slower when you have some amount of `Frames` with plots stacked.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! @HenryYik I am allowing the user to switch between different frames by using radio buttons to select which group of plots they want to view. Is there an easier way to do this so that the frames do not stack necessarily, as you mentioned?

Comment: Easiest way is to destroy the previous Frame before creating a new one. You would have to keep track of the frames you created. Better way is to reuse the same plotting area, but that would require a big change in your code.